# In Papaparser, How to handle multiple values?

Tags: javascript, papaparse

I have a csv like this:

```
name, email
raja, "raja@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com"
```

Note that email has two values.

I want my json to be like:

```
{
   "name": "raja"
    "email": ["raja@gmail.com","xyz@gmail.com"]
}
```

Is there any way to do it in papa parser ?

Comment: `email` has an single string value. I don't think PapaParse has any builtin to reparse the strings it got, but if you're confident enough in your data format, it shouldn't be too hard to search for `,` characters in the parsed data and call `split(',').map(str=>str.trim())`

Comment: But I would advice you to use an other delimiter than the main one (i.e don't use `,`)

Comment: Thanks.. I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser cannot handle your email array format, try to change to something like:

```
name,email
raja,raja@gmail.com|xyz@gmail.com
```

Inside config object do this:

```
var config = {
    //... other config settings
    complete: function (parsed) {
        parsed.data.forEach(row => Object.assign(row, {email: row.email.split("|")}))
    }
};
```